# Trigger a test failure when UBSAN (-fsanitize=undefined) finds undefined behaviour

Tags: c++, ubsan

I have a small unit test here which has undefined behaviour.

Source code:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(test, test)
{
    int k = 0x7fffffff;
    k += 1; // cause integer overflow
}

GTEST_API_ int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

I enable UBSAN in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.12)
project(ub CXX)

find_package(GTest REQUIRED)

add_executable        (ub_test ub_test.cpp)
target_link_libraries (ub_test GTest::GTest)
target_compile_options(ub_test PRIVATE -fsanitize=undefined)
target_link_options   (ub_test PRIVATE -fsanitize=undefined)
```

UBSAN correctly identifies the undefined behaviour:

> ```
> /home/steve/src/ub/ub_test.cpp:6:7: runtime error: signed integer overflow:
> 2147483647 + 1 cannot be represented in type 'int'
> ```

However, my test still passes.

> ```
> [==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
> [----------] Global test environment set-up.
> [----------] 1 test from test
> [ RUN      ] test.test
> /home/steve/src/ub/ub_test.cpp:6:7: runtime error: signed integer overflow:
> 2147483647 + 1 cannot be represented in type 'int'
> [       OK ] test.test (0 ms)
> [----------] 1 test from test (0 ms total)
>
> [----------] Global test environment tear-down
> [==========] 1 test from 1 test suite ran. (0 ms total)
> [  PASSED  ] 1 test.
> ```

Is it possible to trigger a test failure (throw an exception, exit 1, etc) when UBSAN finds an issue?

Comment: maybe you can redirect stdout (or is it stderr?) and assert on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html):

> - `-fsanitize=...`: print a verbose error report and continue execution (default);
> - `-fno-sanitize-recover=...`: print a verbose error report and exit the program;
> - `-fsanitize-trap=...`: execute a trap instruction (doesn’t require UBSan run-time support).
>
> Note that the `trap` / `recover` options do not enable the corresponding sanitizer, and in general need to be accompanied by a suitable `-fsanitize=` flag.

It seems like when you use `-fsanitize=` the exact same thing happens which you're talking about. It notices the undefined behavior and reports it, but continues execution. So appending a `-fno-sanitize-recover=all` should exit the program.

Comment: Ha - RTFM! Thanks! It looks like the correct way to get this is to **add** `-fno-sanitize-recover=all` (ie: in addition to `-fsantize=undefined`)

Comment: @SteveLorimer Ah I see, probably due to the _"Note that the trap / recover options do not enable the corresponding sanitizer, and in general need to be accompanied by a suitable `-fsanitize=` flag."_ I'll edit my post to fix that.

Answer (score 4):

You can try `UBSAN_OPTIONS="halt_on_error=1"` environment variable.

```
UBSAN_OPTIONS="halt_on_error=1" cmake --build cmake-build-UBSAN --target test
```